# Appending route configuration to all routes

Tags: symfony, configuration, url-routing

I'd like to have multilingual site done with Symfony. So I need to add something like:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
contact:
    path:     /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: "pl" }
    requirements:
        _locale: pl|en
```

However I don't want to repeat this on every route I define, so I came up with solution:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    locale.available: pl|en
    locale.default: pl
<...>
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.php" # note '.php'

<!-- language: lang-php -->
# app/config/routing.php
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$configFile = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'routing.yml';
$yaml = new Parser();
try {
    $routes = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents($configFile));
} catch (ParseException $e) {
    printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
}
$collection = new RouteCollection();
foreach ($routes as $name => $def) {
    $route = new Route($def['path']);
    foreach (['defaults', 'requirements', 'options', 'host', 'schemes', 'methods', 'condition'] as $opt) {
        $mtd = 'add'. ucfirst($opt);
        if(isset($def[$opt])) $route->$mtd($def[$opt]);
    }
    $collection->add($name, $route);
}
$collection->addRequirements(['_locale' => "%locale.available%"]);
$collection->addDefaults(['_locale'=>"%locale.default%"]);

return $collection;
?>

# app/config/routing_dev.yml
<...>
_main:
    resource: routing.php
```

Still, I'm rather new to Symfony2 (now 3), so I wonder... Is there a better way to accomplish such appending route config to all the routes? Perhaps there are more flexible or more "right" ways of doing such things in Symfony? Or should I hook into some existing mechanism?

Comment: For that kind of routing I suggest you this bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom route loader that extends the default one. See here for more info:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html

For example if you wanna support yml, xml and annotations you'd need to extend the Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader, Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\XmlFileLoader and Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Routing\AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader incorporate the logic you have to the load method and you'd need to change the 

`sensio_framework_extra.routing.loader.annot_class.class,routing.loader.yml.class and routing.loader.xml.class`
parameters to point to your new classes.

Defining your own route_loader seems like the less hacky solution